# StringObservable.from(InputStream).share() cause immediate MissingBackPressure

Tags: java, rx-java

I want to read my `InputStream` in `Observable` and emit parsed data (let's say `DataPacket`). I also want to have different `subscribers` to handle different types of `DataPacket` (each `subscriber` will apply it's own filter to initial `observable`). That means, that `Observable` should share state between different `subscribers`. I decided to use `share()` but encountered `MissingBackpressureException`.

The following code fails:

```
readSubscription = StringObservable.from(mInStream,1024)
        .share()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .subscribe(new Action1<byte[]>() {
            @Override
            public void call(byte[] bytes) {

            }
        });
```

I do nothing in my `subscribe` method - `subscriber` should be quick enough.

Everything is fine, if I remove `share()`. This code works:

```
readSubscription = StringObservable.from(mInStream,1024)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .subscribe(new Action1<byte[]>() {
            @Override
            public void call(byte[] bytes) {

            }
        });
```

I understand, that `share()` can be an expensive operation and my `InputStream` produces a lot of messages (~100 messages per second).

**My question**: How to implement an `Observable` which read `InputStream` and share the state between different `Subscribers`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current v0.22 doesn't support backpressure properly so you should use `onBackpressureBuffer` to avoid the `MissingBackpressureException` for now. I'll see if we can release the latest code which should work.

In addition, using `share()` can be surprising, because it does reference counting on the subscribers. You can't really subscribe all your subscribers at once with it and some of them may not receive all values from the start. Instead, you can use the `publish()` operator and call `connect()` on the returned observable once all your subscribers have subscribed.

You can also use `cache()` which will replay the source to any late subscriber, but it doesn't support backpressure yet either and you need to use `onBackpressureBuffer` with it too.